# how to use spring data mongo in a springboot using aggregation fraimwork

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

i have created a mongo query as follows

```
db.organizers.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "projects",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "created_by",
      as: "TotalProject"
    }},
  { $unwind: "$TotalProject" },
  { $unwind: "$TotalProject.cost_codes" },
  { $unwind: "$TotalProject.cost_codes.donations" },
  {$group: {
      _id: "$TotalProject.cost_codes.code",
      TotalDonation: {
        $sum: {
          $toDouble: "$TotalProject.cost_codes.donations.amount"}}}}])
```

now i want to convert the above query in spring data mongo so i write a code in the following way

```
public List<TotalDonations> updatingOrganizerEntityWithProjects(){



        LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
                .from("projects")
                .localField("_id")
                .foreignField("created_by")
                .as("TotalProject");


        UnwindOperation unwindOperation_1 = Aggregation.unwind("TotalProject");
        UnwindOperation unwindOperation_2 = Aggregation.unwind("TotalProject.cost_Codes");
        UnwindOperation unwindOperation_3 = Aggregation.unwind("TotalProject.cost_Codes.donations");
        GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("_id").sum("TotalProject.cost_Codes.donations.amount").as("TotalDonation");

        Aggregation aggregation1 = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation,unwindOperation_1,unwindOperation_2,unwindOperation_3,groupOperation);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation1,"organizers",TotalDonations.class).getMappedResults();
    }
```

the return type is hoving 0 element then i have tried to do it in some other way as follows

```
public List<TotalDonations> updatingOrganizerEntityWithProjects(){
    LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("projects")
            .localField("_id")
            .foreignField("created_by")
            .as("TotalProject");

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation);

    mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,"organizers", Document.class).getMappedResults();

    // This is the only change you made to your code.
    UnwindOperation unwindOperation_1 = Aggregation.unwind("TotalProject");
    UnwindOperation unwindOperation_2 = Aggregation.unwind("TotalProject.cost_Codes");
    UnwindOperation unwindOperation_3 = Aggregation.unwind("TotalProject.cost_Codes.donations");
    GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("_id").sum("TotalProject.cost_Codes.donations.amount").as("TotalDonation");

    Aggregation aggregation1 = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwindOperation_1,unwindOperation_2,unwindOperation_3,groupOperation);

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation1, Document.class,TotalDonations.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

it is giving methe fllowing error

```
he above code is returning the following error
2023-09-28T19:10:31.245+05:30 WARN 9452 --- [nio-8091-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot determine collection name from type 'org.bson.Document'. Is it a store native type?]
```

i have also creaded a model as follows to hold the data

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TotalDonations {
    @Field("_id")
    private String id;

    private Double TotalDonation;


}
```

i am trying to bind the data of organization id and total donation in the above model TotalDonations but either it is returning 0 value in the list or it cant find the field as it is getting the field that TotalProject that i got after lookup, in short i want to feed the result that i have got after lookup function to the group for grouping operation.